# Taking screenshot not working in window service c#

Tags: c#, web-services, screenshot

I am using to capture the screen and upload the image array to server. but its giving the win32 exception when taking screenshot, my code is as:

```
            private static Bitmap bmpScreenshot;
            private static Graphics gfxScreenshot;
            bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height ,PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

            gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);

            gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

            System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            bmpScreenshot.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            byte[] bmpBytes = ms.GetBuffer();
            bmpScreenshot.Dispose();
            ms.Close();
```

The specific error coming as: Service cannot be started. System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The handle is invalid
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen(Int32 sourceX, Int32 sourceY, Int32 destinationX, Int32 destinationY, Size blockRegionSize, CopyPixelOperation copyPixelOperation)
   at ScrrenShare.ScreenShare.TraceService() in F:\Umesh Projects\ScreenShare\ScreenShare\ScreenShare\ScreenShare.cs:line 48
   at ScrrenShare.ScreenShare.OnStart(String[] args) in F:\Umesh Projects\ScreenShare\ScreenShare\ScreenShare\ScreenShare.cs:line 29
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.ServiceQueuedMainCallback(Object state)
   Please let me know solution.The code is working fine in Window form application Thanks in adv.

Comment: What is the specific error?

Comment: The question is updated with the specific error. thanks for replying me... The code is working fine in window form application...

Answer (score 2):

Did you do this step?

Set the properties of the service in administrative tools -> services -> right click your service -> goto properties -> under Log On tab check allow to interact with desktop.

Comment: Its solved the Win32 exception issue. but its saving as blank screen. its not capturing the original image. Just blank image showing. Let me know any idea.

Comment: Do you have it running under the same login as the active user?

Comment: Yes, I running in same user as the active user...!

Comment: Did not solve the issue. Taking screenshot only works when actually a user is logged in.

Comment: If no user is logged in...windows has no need to display a screen....I would hazard to guess.