# Outlook Redemption Error: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The handle is invalid

Tags: c#, outlook, nunit, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

I have test suit for outlook MAPI created in C#, which uses Redemption.

Which executing below try{} catch{} block it is throwing below exception. Any idea what needs to be done?

```
try
{
    _RDOSession = new Redemption.RDOSessionClass();
    _RDOSession.MAPIOBJECT = OutlookConnection.Instance.nameSpace.MAPIOBJECT;
    _MAPIUtils = new MAPIUtils();
}
catch (System.Exception e)
{
    throw new HarnessException("OutlookRedemption threw exception for _RDOSession", e);
}

.
.
.
.

try
{
    _OutlookApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass();
}
catch (System.Exception e)
{
    throw new HarnessException("OutlookConnection threw exception for _OutlookApplication", e);
}
```

**It shows below errors in order:**

OutlookConnection threw exception for _OutlookApplication
SyncHarness.HarnessException: OutlookConnection threw exception for _OutlookApplication ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80080005): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005.
at SyncHarness.OutlookConnection..ctor()

OutlookRedemption threw exception for _RDOSession SyncHarness.HarnessException: OutlookRedemption threw exception for _RDOSession ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The handle is invalid at System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen(Int32 sourceX, Int32 sourceY, Int32 destinationX, Int32 destinationY, Size blockRegionSize, CopyPixelOperation copyPixelOperation)

Tried modifying registry according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/application-management/error-8008005-when-start-complus-applications

But didn't help.

Comment: I would assume you are leaking COM resources. Are you sure you are releasing everything correctly after use? Your link is about COM+ i doubt that COM+ is involved here.

Comment: From the error details it's clear you aren't showing all the relevant code here.

Comment: Do you get this exception when running the code outside of unit tests (unattended)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`0x80080005` is `CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE`, most likely this happens if the security context of your app and Outlook are different. if either app is running with elevated privileges (Run As Administrator), make sure that either both do, or none.

Answer (score 0):

> OutlookRedemption threw exception for _RDOSession ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The handle is invalid at System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen(Int32 sourceX, Int32 sourceY, Int32 destinationX, Int32 destinationY, Size blockRegionSize, CopyPixelOperation copyPixelOperation)

Sounds like the Redemption library is trying to take a screenshot when the handle is invalid. This is a possible scenario when running the code under unattended scenario. See [Taking screenshot not working in window service c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20987344/taking-screenshot-not-working-in-window-service-c-sharp) for more information.

Comment: Redemption does no such thing. And it cannot possibly call .Net methods (such as System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen) since it is an unamanaged native dll.

Comment: Good to know. But the Redemption library comes with interop libraries that can do everything in .Net. So, it is not obvious whether it does something like that or not.

Comment: The interop dll that comes with Redemption is the result of importing Redemption type library to .Net using tlbImp.exe. It is nothing but a glorified binary header file with no executable code. It works one way only - if you want to use Redemption in .Net. It cannot be possibly used to allow Redemption to call into .Net, even if it needed to (it does not).

Comment: You can add any business logic to interop libraries. I am aware how they are generated.

Comment: There is no need to explain the theory with which I am pretty familiar. We have never seen the source code of the Redemption library, so it is not obvious what the library does under the hood. Any extra .net specific logic can be put to the interop assemblies with which the Redemption is delivered. Hope my way of thinking is clear now.

Comment: I know you like to argue for the sake of arguing, but you really can't if you are using tlbImp.exe - it is really just the contents of the type library. Open it in ILSpy.exe or any utility like that.

Comment: Not at all. If you say you didn't add anything like that - I trust you. But who knows that? It was not obvious how the error message is related to Redemption. I think you agree that it points directly to the code for making screen captures.